# How to unlock Windows-10 Screen Using python program

Tags: python-3.x

I tried this but do the keyboard library work when the windows is locked

```
import keyboard as key
key.press('win+l')  
key.press('enter')  
key.press('2')  
key.press('0')  
key.press('2')  
key.press('0')  
key.press('enter')
```

Can any one help me in this issue

Comment: Seems like a bad idea if the screen could be unlocked from a program.

Comment: yeah but if you can do that then we can unlock just by our voice command right